# How to suppress warnings in Qt Creator

Tags: linux, qt, g++, qt-creator, compiler-warnings

I'm wondering if it is possible to suppress compiler specific warnings in Qt-Creator.

My g++-4.5 prints:

> warning: enumeral and non-enumeral type in conditional expression

I would like to get rid of it, because it's very annoying.

- Ubuntu 11.04 x64
- g++-4.5
- QtCreator 2.01
- Qt 4.7

Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

You need to use this:

> QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wno-enum-compare

if you get a warning that ends in **-Wenum-compare**, for example.

Also, note that some warnings cannot be suppressed as per the GCC documentation
[take a look at this for ones that you can't suppress](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html), that way you are not given the
false idea that your flags aren't working right.

The best way to know if the flags are being passed to the compiler, obviously, is to look at the compiler output, and make sure your flags are there, you should see **-Wno-enum-compare** in the command line, for example, even if the flag does not suppress anything. You'd be surprised how hard it can be to find information about stuff like this, it took some digging and I ended up finding it from the auto-complete that works when editing .pro files, if you have problems editing your .pro files, hit **Ctrl+Space** (or start typing a word and hit **Shift+Home**), to get a list of valid things you can use in your .pro file just like any other usual source file. It helped me find the right thing (**QMAKE_CXXFLAGS**, as it turns out, is usually not what people suggest, for some reason)... Oh yeah and this is about Qt version 4.8, creator 2.4, so it may have changed, since this post (they seem to like to do that a lot, i saw the newer versions already have changed drastically).

Comment: Does not work. I am using Qt Creator 4.1.0 (4.1.0-rc1)

Answer (score 2):

I have looked through gcc warning options. Gcc has option `-Wenum-compare` which is responsible for the warning, however there is no `-Wno-enum-compare`. The `-Wenum-compare` option is most likely set by `-Wall` unless it is explicitly set. So I would suggest to disable `-Wall`

Answer (score 2):

```
linux-g++ {
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON = -Wall -Wextra -Wno-enum-compare
}
```

or for any system using g++

```
*-g++ {
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON = -Wall -Wextra -Wno-enum-compare
}
```

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-advanced-usage.html
- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: Thanks. Adding, if you add "CONFIG += warn_off", then it'll use the flags you set in "QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_OFF" instead of "QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON", which by default causes Wall and Wextra to be turned off..

Answer (score 0):

You probably have two choices:

1. fix the warning itself (the above looks like you probably need a cast)
2. find the name of the warnings you want to remove issued by g++ and then add them in your .pro file to the CFLAGS with a 'no-' in front.  Something like:

   CFLAGS += -Wno-my-super-warning-I-found

Comment: Thanks, this works for a general warning, but unfortunately not for this case...I don't know how to remove that warning...

Answer (score 0):

For some piece of code:

```
QT_WARNING_PUSH
QT_WARNING_DISABLE_GCC("-Wenum-compare")

// Some code than throwns warnings

QT_WARNING_POP
```