# Disable -Wall compiler warnings in a Qt project?

Tags: c++, qt, warnings, qmake, compiler-flags

I am compiling a 3rd party library and don't care to fix the warnings present in the library, but I don't want them polluting the *Issues* pane in Qt Creator.

I've tried following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18454509/disable-msvc-compiler-warning-in-qt-creator), but there is no compiler flag to disable `-Wall` after it has been enabled, such as with `-Wno-enum-compare`.

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9065431/446554), I tried removing the flag like so:

```
CFLAGS -= -Wall
```

But that didn't work either. So I tried [this advice](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/33484-disabeling-unused-parameter-warnings):

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_OFF -= -Wall
```

Still nothing.

So I looked in the generated `Makefile` and found this:

```
CFLAGS        = -pipe -g -fPIC -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -pipe -g -fPIC -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT $(DEFINES)
```

So I tried removing the flag from those two variables:

```
CFLAGS -= -Wall
CXXFLAGS -= -Wall
```

Still nothing. How are you supposed to remove this compiler flag?!

Answer (score 25):

The simplest solution is:

```
CONFIG += warn_off
```

<sub>Thanks to peppe in comments.</sub>

## Explanation

The `-Wall` flag gets inserted into the `Makefile` by these two variables:

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS_WARN_ON
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON
```

So to remove `-Wall`, you need to remove it from *both* of those variables.

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS_WARN_ON -= -Wall
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON -= -Wall
```

`warn_off` does just that.

Comment: The non-hackish way is probably `CONFIG += warn_off`. As a general way of debugging "where is this variable/option/... coming from?", you can run `qmake -d`, `qmake -d -d`, etc.; this will give you many useful clues.

Comment: @peppe Awesome - thanks. I was totally unaware of this!

Answer (score 8):

As "peppe" also noted in the comment, the Qt'ish way is this according to the documentation below: `CONFIG += warn_off/on`

`warn_on`: The compiler should output as many warnings as possible. This is ignored if warn_off is specified.

`warn_off`: The compiler should output as few warnings as possible.

The CONFIG documentation can be found in [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qmake-variable-reference.html#config).

The `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_OFF/ON` variables do not need to be set explicitly as they are handled by qmake.